# What's the meaning and the origin of "skewer a sacred cow ?"

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I've read this idom from an article, and it seems that the phrase "**skewer a sacred cow**" mean "to criticize" but I am not very sure.

Does anyone know the exact meaning and the origin of this idom?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sacred+cow

Comment: Macmillan's definition: **sacred cow** [noun] something that many people think is too important to change, question, or criticize. **or skewer**. [last two words not in original]

Comment: _Sacred cow_ is an idiom; _skewer a sacred cow_ is not.

Comment: @Colin I'm betting it gets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sacred cow**

The figurative use of the term 'sacred cow', to refer to a project or process that is immune from tampering, is American in origin and also dates from the late 19th century.

Source: [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/309250.html)

To skewer a sacred cow, means to defy what is generally held as indisputable.